# Does documentation exist that shows the evolutionary connection between common horses and the okapi?

Tags: evolution

I'm trying to put together some documentation on the relation between the common (modern) horse and the okapi. I've found a tree that shows that connection but it has no references. I'm hoping that someone has documented this connection somehow.

Comment: Can you add a link to the tree?

Comment: Okapi is like a giraffe right... so you have to go back to a pretty basal ungulate.

Comment: I have started to recreate the tree image that I found in Google Docs as a Drawing. Here is the link: https://docs.google.com/drawings/d/19NuQ0BgnUKuYqhabovdEI-UG6Tj3OfcEOb8h23UThIk/edit?usp=sharing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[tolweb.org](http://tolweb.org/tree/) is your friend!

Because the okapi and the horse are not so closely related you will probably find several articles on the subject. Okapi belongs to the order of [artiodactyla](http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Artiodactyla) while the horse belongs to the order of [perissodactyla](http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perissodactyla). They are both mammals, eutheria, [ungalata (superorder)](http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ungulata).

[Here](http://tolweb.org/Eutheria/15997) is the tree of the eutheria (within the mammals) from tolweb. You have approximatively 150 references. You can click on [perissodactyla](http://tolweb.org/Perissodactyla/15980) and [artiodactyla](http://tolweb.org/Artiodactyla/15976) and you will find 100 more references.

These two references may help you (I only read the titles)

- [Graur, D., M. Gouy, and L. Duret. 1997. Evolutionary affinities of the order Perissodactyla and the phylogenetic status of the superordinal taxa Ungulata and Altungulata. Molecular Phylogenetics and Evolution 7:195-200](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/9126561)
- [Xu, X. F., A. Janke, and U. Arnason. 1996. The complete mitochondrial DNA sequence of the greater Indian rhinoceros, Rhinoceros unicornis, and the phylogenetic relationship among Carnivora, Perissodactyla, and Artiodactyla (plus Cetacea). Molecular Biology and Evolution 13:1167-1173](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/8896369)

Comment: My name is Casey and I approve of this message +1